# Can the AutoReviewComments script be built into Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: feature-request

Can the [AutoReviewComments userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/24208) be built into Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about because that script already works for Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @jokerdino, I am talking about building the script in AU. Meaning not downloading greasemonkey, and installing the script. But, as a reward when one reaches X amount of reputation.

Comment: If you put it that way, it is already available for users going through the review queue. Is that not enough?

Comment: @jokerdino  Its more of a convenience for users that have a significant amount of rep, to provide them a tool that is readily available when needed.

Comment: @jokerdino "available for users going through the review queue" ...is it? I've never seen anything of the sort (or maybe I've missed it, or it's only in one of the queues I can't access yet...?)

Comment: @JezW [Read about it here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137363/177471)

Comment: @jokerdino Aah, so it's only in the LQ queue then (if I understand correctly / there haven't been changees since). Fair enough. But an expansion of that could be useful, I feel.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I like this one , I have gone through script. Its looks fine and nice. For Ask Ubuntu I think only one single modification have to do is the site name and I think I have done that, any way I need some one to verify along with me.

http://pastebin.com/xJpYG031

Comment: site name ? @Mateo I already did mentioned as one only

Comment: Why did you need to modify the site name? It should work out of the box.

Comment: I have seen there , There is no mention of Ask Ubuntu as site name so that I cant work for Ask Ubuntu perhaps